# Is Ninefingers Dead Yet?

Tags: joe-abercrombie, the-first-law

It's been a few years since I read through the series.

I have the three The First Law books (The Blade Itself, Before They Are Hanged & Last Argument of Kings) & the three that followed those (Best Served Cold, The Heroes & Red Country), he's still alive (though older) at the end of those.

Have there been any others since those that I've missed, is Logan still out there somewhere waiting for another story or is he "back to the mud" already?

Comment: Say one thing about Logen Ninefingers, say you're not sure if he's alive or dead.